RDS Proxy for Postgres DB without creating secrets in AWS Secrets Manager
I have a very standard use case. (I already explored on internet and went through various AWS docs but didn't find concrete and clear answers for my questions.)

I have a RDS Postgres instance and I want to use RDS proxy to access this RDS instance.

I have created 5 databases on this RDS instance

I have different application pods (running in AWS EKS cluster) which connects to different databases created on the same RDS instance

The Database creds (username and password) are stored in k8s secrets and are mounted to respective application pods.


Now, When I tried creating RDS proxy, I found that It is mandatory to create(stored in AWS Secrets Manager) and provide the secrets ARN during RDS proxy creation.
My assumption was - With RDS proxy we will get proxy endpoint and simply replace this end-point in my application pods, The DB username and password I already have using k8s secrets.
Questions :

Is it mandatory to also create and store the DB secrets in AWS secrets Manager to use RDS proxy ?

If RDS proxy can already access to RDS instance (using provided IAM role), then can I not simply connect to RDS instance using RDS proxy endpoint with the same DB username and password which my application pods can get from k8s secrets ?

Let's say If It is mandatory to create secrets and store in AWS secrets manager to user RDS proxy - It means I have to create 5 secrets for my 5 application databases ?

Can I not simply skip to create and store DB secrets in AWS secrets manager too to use RDS proxy ?


Thanks in advance.
